# Definition of unit normal vector in do Carmo

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, submanifold

Let $S\subset R^3$ be a regular surface. Suppose that $\mathbf{x}:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to S$ is a parametrization of $S$ at $p\in S$. Then for every $q\in \mathbf{x}(U)$, do Carmo defines a unit normal vector by
$$N(q) = \frac{\mathbf{x}_u \wedge \mathbf{x}_v}{\lvert \mathbf{x}_u \wedge \mathbf{x}_v\rvert}(q).$$
What I don't understand here is that $\mathbf{x}_u$ and $\mathbf{x}_v$ are defined on $U$, so the above expression isn't defined. Shouldn't it be
$$N(q) = \frac{\mathbf{x}_u \wedge \mathbf{x}_v}{\lvert \mathbf{x}_u \wedge \mathbf{x}_v\rvert}(\mathbf{x}^{-1}(q))?$$

Comment: Just for completeness: as I recall, do Carmo is viewing tangent vectors on $S$  at $q$  as elements of the ambient space i.e., $\mathbf{x}_u$ and $\mathbf{x}_v \in T_q(S)\subset T_q({\mathbb R}^3)= {\mathbb R}^3$ - do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's right.

Comment: It is customary (although not 100% pedantic) in differential geometry to talk about and visualize the unit normal as a function *on* the surface but, when it comes to a calculation, to resort to "local coordinates" (i.e., a parametrization).

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: Sure. If you want another source to read, help yourself to my (free) text. It's linked in my profile.

Comment: I appreciate it!